# Hibernate search with spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am just wondering what is the advantage of having hibernate search in my spring boot application if I just can get data using hibernate HQL ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Hibernate Search uses Lucene, which provides more searching capabilities and indexes, like full-text searches, stemming, stop-words removal, etc.

Comment: Also it uses Antrl library  , on this library HQL is built)